# Adjust the size of fit nodes in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, fit

I have a problem with controlling the size of fit nodes in tikzpicture. I want the fit node to cover all the area but it does not seem to be working. I searched around but I have not found the solution yet. I would like to ask for your help. Thank you very much. Below is the tex of the figure. I also the image illustrating the wanted target.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}

\begin{document}
% Define the flowchart
\tikzstyle{startstop} = [draw, rounded rectangle, text centered, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{io} = [trapezium, trapezium left angle=70, trapezium right angle=110, text centered, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{process} = [rectangle,inner sep=-0.1ex, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=4cm, draw=black]
\tikzstyle{decision} = [diamond, aspect=2, inner sep=-1ex,  text centered, text width=4cm,  draw=black]
\tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth, rounded corners]
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.4cm]
\node (start) [startstop] {Start};
\node (in1) [io, below = 0.5 of start, align= center] {$V$: an input sample vector \\ $\alpha$: a user-specified number};
\node (pro1) [process, below of=in1] {Do something};
\node (pro2) [process, below of=pro1] {Do something};
\node (pro3) [process, right of=pro2, xshift=4cm] {Do something};
\node (dec1) [decision, above of=pro3, yshift=0.4cm] {Check condition?};
\node (out1) [io, above of = dec1, yshift=0.4cm] {Output something};
\node (stop) [startstop, above = 0.5 of out1] {Stop};
\node (fit1) [dashed, rounded corners, fill=none, fit=(in1) (pro2), draw] {};
\node (fit2) [dashed, rounded corners, fill=none, fit=(pro3) (out1), draw] {};
\node[rotate=90, anchor=south] at (fit1.west) {The first step};
\node[rotate=90, anchor=south] at (fit2.west) {The second step};

\draw [arrow] (start) -- (in1);
\draw [arrow] (in1) -- (pro1);
\draw [arrow] (pro1) -- (pro2);
\draw [arrow] (pro2) -- (pro3);
\draw [arrow] (pro3) -- (dec1);
\draw (dec1.east) node[above right, xshift=0.4cm] {False}; \node[above left] at (dec1.north) {True};
\draw [arrow] (dec1.east) -- +(1,0) |- (pro3);
\draw [arrow] (dec1) -- (out1);
\draw [arrow] (out1) -- (stop);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The two solutions given by @Zarko and Schrödinger's cat work well. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

Node with `fit=<node name>` actually consider width of the text in node with shapes `trapezium` and `diamond` and not their shapes extremes. This means, that we need to consider `<node name>.bottom left corner` and `<node name>.top right  corner` at trapezium and `<node name>.west` and `<node name>.east` at diamond shapes.

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                fit,
                positioning,
                shapes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
   node distance = 8mm and 12mm,
     start chain = A going below,
     start chain = B going above,
     base/.style = {draw, align=center, 
                    inner sep=2mm, on chain=A, join=by arr},
startstop/.style = {base, rounded rectangle},
       io/.style = {base, text width=42mm, trapezium, trapezium stretches body,
                    trapezium left angle=75, trapezium right angle=105},
  process/.style = {base, text width=44mm, minimum height=1cm},
 decision/.style = {base, text width=40mm, diamond, aspect=2, inner xsep=-4mm},
      arr/.style = {-stealth}
                        ]
\node   [startstop] {Start};                        % A-1
\node   [io] {$V$: an input sample vector \\ 
              $\alpha$: a user-specified number};
\node   [process] {Do something};
\node   [process] {Do something};                   % A-4
    \node (f1) [draw, rounded corners, dashed, 
                fit=(A-2.bottom left corner) (A-2.top right corner) (A-4),
                label={[rotate=90, anchor=south]left:The first step}] {};
%  
    \begin{scope}[base/.append style={on chain=B}]  % B-1
\node   [process, right=of A-4] {Do something};
\node   [decision]      {Check condition?};
\node   [io]            {Output something};
\node   [startstop]     {Stop};                     % B-4
    \end{scope}
%
\draw[arr]  (A-4) -- (B-1);
\draw[arr] (B-2.east) node (false) [above right] {False} -- + (1,0) |- (B-1);
\node[above left] at (B-2.north) {True};
%
    \node (f2) [draw, rounded corners, dashed, 
                fit=(B-1) (B-3.bottom left corner) (B-3.top right corner) (false),
                label={[rotate=90,anchor=south]left:The second step}] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note: 
node names are determined by chain name: `A-i` for nodes in the left branch of the flowchart and `B-i` for nodes in the right branch.

Comment: Thanks for your kind answer Zarko, How can I make \node(f2) cover all this arrow (`\draw[arr] (B-2.east) node[above right] {False} -- + (1,0) |- (B-1);`) and the False node as my attached image?

Comment: @Clark, of course it can. I overlooked this.See edited answer.

Answer (score 6):

This answer focuses on the (IMHO really interesting) question why the fits are too tight. The key in understanding this behavior is in the lines

```
\def\tikz@lib@fit@scan@handle#1{%
  \iftikz@shapeborder%
    % Ok, fit all four external anchors, if they exist
    \tikz@lib@fit@adjust{\pgfpointanchor{\tikz@shapeborder@name}{west}}%
    \tikz@lib@fit@adjust{\pgfpointanchor{\tikz@shapeborder@name}{east}}%
    \tikz@lib@fit@adjust{\pgfpointanchor{\tikz@shapeborder@name}{north}}%
    \tikz@lib@fit@adjust{\pgfpointanchor{\tikz@shapeborder@name}{south}}%
  \else%
    \tikz@lib@fit@adjust{#1}%
  \fi%
  \tikz@lib@fit@scan%
}%
```

of `tikzlibraryfit.code.tex`. This tacitly assumes that anything that fits the the `west`, `east`, `north` and `south` anchors will fit the whole node. However, for the trapezium this is not the case, see p. 790 of pgfmanual v3.1.5

[image]

That means that for the trapezium shapes we need to fit other anchors. In the case at hand these are

```
\node (fit1) [dashed, rounded corners, fill=none, fit=(in1.top right corner)
  (in1.bottom left corner) (pro2), draw] {};
\node (fit2) [dashed, rounded corners, fill=none, fit=(pro3) (out1.top right corner)
  (out1.bottom left corner) (false), draw] {};
```

There are several other things changed (no more `\tikzstyle`, proper positioning etc.) but describing them in detail will just distract from the main point: using the above-mentioned anchors solves the problem.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,shapes.misc,shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[startstop/.style = {rounded rectangle},
       io/.style = {text width=42mm, trapezium, trapezium stretches body,
                    trapezium left angle=75, trapezium right angle=105},
  process/.style = {text width=44mm, minimum height=1cm},
 decision/.style = {text width=40mm, diamond, aspect=2, inner xsep=-4mm},
 lbl/.style={draw=none,inner sep=2pt},
      node distance=1cm and 1.6cm]
 \begin{scope}[nodes= {draw, align=center,inner sep=2mm}]
  \node (start) [startstop] {Start};
  \node (in1) [io, below = 0.5 of start, align= center] {$V$: an input sample vector \\ $\alpha$: a user-specified number};
  \node (pro1) [process, below=of in1] {Do something};
  \node (pro2) [process, below=of pro1] {Do something};
  \node (pro3) [process, right=of pro2] {Do something};
  \node (dec1) [decision, above=of pro3] {Check condition?};
  \node (out1) [io, above=of dec1] {Output something};
  \node (stop) [startstop, above=of out1] {Stop};
  \node (fit1) [dashed, rounded corners, fill=none, fit=(in1.top right corner)
  (in1.bottom left corner) (pro2), draw] {};
  \draw[-stealth] (dec1.east) -- +(1,0) node[above=0.5ex,lbl](false){False} |- (pro3);
  \node (fit2) [dashed, rounded corners, fill=none, fit=(pro3) (out1.top right corner)
  (out1.bottom left corner) (false), draw] {};
 \end{scope} 
 \node[rotate=90, anchor=south] at (fit1.west) {The first step};
 \node[rotate=90, anchor=south] at (fit2.west) {The second step};
 \begin{scope}[-stealth]
  \draw (start) -- (in1);
  \draw (in1) -- (pro1);
  \draw (pro1) -- (pro2);
  \draw (pro2) -- (pro3);
  \draw (pro3) -- (dec1);
  \draw (dec1) -- node[left=0.5ex,lbl]{True} (out1);
  \draw (out1) -- (stop);     
 \end{scope}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course one may not want to guess the anchors one has include. One way to avoid this is to work with `local bounding box`es. In principle one could then drop `fit` completely but I keep it since the question is on `fit`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit,shapes.misc,shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[startstop/.style = {rounded rectangle},
       io/.style = {text width=42mm, trapezium, trapezium stretches body,
                    trapezium left angle=75, trapezium right angle=105},
  process/.style = {text width=44mm, minimum height=1cm},
  decision/.style = {text width=40mm, diamond, aspect=2, inner xsep=-4mm},
  lbl/.style={draw=none,inner sep=2pt},
      node distance=1cm and 1.6cm]
 \begin{scope}[nodes= {draw, align=center,inner sep=2mm}]
  \node (start) [startstop] {Start};
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=F1]
   \node (in1) [io, below = 0.5 of start, align= center] {$V$: an input sample vector \\ $\alpha$: a user-specified number};
   \node (pro1) [process, below=of in1] {Do something};
   \node (pro2) [process, below=of pro1] {Do something};
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=F2]
   \node (pro3) [process, right=of pro2] {Do something};
   \node (dec1) [decision, above=of pro3] {Check condition?};
   \node (out1) [io, above=of dec1] {Output something};
  \end{scope}
  \draw[-stealth] (dec1.east) -- +(1,0) node[above=0.5ex,lbl](false){False} |- (pro3);
  \node (stop) [startstop, above=of out1] {Stop};
  \node (fit1) [dashed, rounded corners, fill=none, fit=(F1), draw] {};
  \node (fit2) [dashed, rounded corners, fill=none, fit=(F2)(false), draw] {};
 \end{scope} 
 \node[rotate=90, anchor=south] at (fit1.west) {The first step};
 \node[rotate=90, anchor=south] at (fit2.west) {The second step};
 \begin{scope}[-stealth]
  \draw (start) -- (in1);
  \draw (in1) -- (pro1);
  \draw (pro1) -- (pro2);
  \draw (pro2) -- (pro3);
  \draw (pro3) -- (dec1);
  \draw (dec1) -- node[left,lbl]{True} (out1);
  \draw (out1) -- (stop);     
 \end{scope}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your expalaination Schrödinger's cat, How can I make \node (fit2) cover all the arrow (`\draw (dec1.east) -- +(1,0) node[above]{False} |- (pro3);`) and the False node as my attached image?